# Trouble with merging two data frames in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, insert

I need to create a column in a dataframe through the concatenation of two other columns and then with that column bring a column from another dataframe (something like a LOOKUP in Excel).

The code i tried is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('/Inv.xlsx')
```

[First Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFPvX.png)

```
df5 = pd.read_excel('/Min.xlsx')
```

[Second Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Rjd.png)

(Creating the column)

```
df1['CONK'] = df1['Local'].apply(str) + df1['Cód'].apply(str)
```

(Changing the column type)

```
df5['CONK'] = df5['CONK'].astype(str).astype(int)
df1['CONK'] = df1['CONK'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

I’ve tried this:

```
pd.merge(df1, df5, how='left', left_on='CONK', right_on='CONK')
```

and this:

```
df1.insert(2, 'MIN_PRES', df1['CONK'].map(df5.set_index('CONK')['MIN_PRES']))
```

and can’t get the right results.

Can anybody help me with this problem? This is what I’m looking for (red values are invented).
[Expected Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDYoB.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please provide what you're getting and what isn't right about it? And please [do not insert images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) - instead, try to develop a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: With both strategies, I only get 'NAN'.

Comment: Please paste your data, results, and full code as code blocks, not images. Thanks!